# Trying to fit a html content (googlemap) between a header and a footer - CSS - HTML

Tags: html, css, google-maps

Im trying to fit a googlemap map between a header and a footer, as main content, but the map get the 100% and pushes the footer down, I want fit the map between them so that if I resize the window all content will adjust automatically without appear a left bar to scroll the content, but something I missing, please could somebody give me a hand with it?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* Required to absolutely position the footer */
}

#footer {
    height: 20px; /* Define height of the footer */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Sit it on the bottom */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; /* As wide as it's allowed */
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* This should match the height of the footer */
}
    </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">Header added just for demonstration purposes</div>
        <div id="content"><div id="map-canvas"></div></div>
        <div id="footer">And this is my footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Greetings and thanks in advance.
Edited : Here the jsfiddle link, with a little changes, but with the same issue, if you try to get: the header, the map and the footer in one view actually you can't, appears the scroll bar because the map is pushing down the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/PYaDq/197/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was fighting with issues like this, I think the key is the absolute positioning and I think this is what you're trying to get:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            }
        #header {
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            }
        #wrapper {
            left: 0px;
            top: 40px;
            bottom: 18px;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #footer {
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width:100%;
        }

        #content {
            top: 1px;
            bottom: 0px;
            /*padding-left: 10px;*/
            overflow: auto;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

    </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </head>
<body>
   <div id="header">Header added just for demonstration purposes</div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">And this is my footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cespinoza/s6Q4V/

Answer (score 0):

i would strongly recommend looking into css3 media queries as an option. a general search will turn up a lot of good resources.

media queries are intended for changing device (and browser) widths and have a similar format to other style tags.  you might have something like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px)
{
    #content
    {
    }
}
```

this will override the style settings at the bounds that you specify.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but my code without change the size had problems to render the design

Comment: @henry_bemis As I said, the map pushes the footer down, I don't know how fix it